# How can I iterate/ transpose /append a data frame to another one?

Tags: pandas, loops, append, transpose

```
for row in range(1, len(df)):

try:
    df_out, orthogroup, len_group = HOG_get_group_stats(df.loc[row, "HOG"])
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for id in range(len(df_out)):
        print(" ")
        temp_df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df_out.iloc[id, :]).T], axis=1)
        temp_df["HOG"] = orthogroup
        temp_df["len_group"] = len_group

    print(temp_df)
except:
    print(row, "no")
```

Here I have a script that does the following:

1. Iterate over **df** and apply the **HOG_get_group_stats** function to the **HOG** column in df and then, get 3 variables as outputs. (Basically, the function creates some stats as a data frame called **df_out**, and extracts some information as two more columns called **orthogroup, len_group**)
2. Create an empty template called **temp_df**
3. Transpose the **df_out** data frame and make it one single row and then, concatenate with the df we used in the beginning as columns.
4. Add **orthogroup, len_group** columns to the end of the **temp_df**

Problem:

It prints out the data however, when I try to see the **temp_df** as a data frame it shows only a single row ( probably the last one) means that my concatenation of several data frames doesn't work.

Questions:

1. How can I iterate and then append a data frame as columns?
2. Is there an easier way to iterate over a data frame? (e.g. iterrow)
3. Is there a better way to transpose rows to columns in a data frame? ( e.g. pivot, melt)

Any help would be appreciated!!

You can find the sample files to df, df_out,temp_df and expected output_sample table here :
[Sample_files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iRL5UqfDTfx-GX4QjAgm6qq1uGXz8fdj?usp=sharing)

[image: expected output table looks like this]

Comment: can you add some sample values of df_out, orthogroup, len_group and the way you want output

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I've added the sample files into the description. Please let me know if it's still not clear.